# Check if SKNode has a certain action running

Tags: swift3, sprite-kit, skaction, sknode

I have a SKNode that is running different actions. 
Depending on the running action I want to trigger other behaviours. For  that I would need to find out how to check which action is currently running on my SKNode.
I know of .hasActions() but this is returning a general true/false value, which does not help me in my situation.

Does anyone have a better solution?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you start running an action, you assign a key to it using this method:

```
yourNode.run(someAction, withKey: "someKey")
```

You can then get the action with your key using:

```
yourNode.action(forKey: "someKey")
```

If the above cal returns nil, that means the node is not running the action!